# Loop through file with unique identifer and compute cumulative sum

Tags: text-processing, awk, array, bioinformatics, pattern-matching

I have a large text file, as shown below, where column1-colum3 define a region and fourth column is unique identifier. The column 6 is assigned value of the region.

```
chr6    26204834    26204839    region1 +   119.862 chr6    26204834    26204835    +   0.982
chr6    26204834    26204839    region1 +   119.862 chr6    26204835    26204836    +   8.487
chr6    26204834    26204839    region1 +   119.862 chr6    26204836    26204837    +   2.664
chr6    26204834    26204839    region1 +   119.862 chr6    26204837    26204838    +   105.065
chr6    26204834    26204839    region1 +   119.862 chr6    26204838    26204839    +   2.664
chr18   72218300    72218307    region2 +   113.879 chr18   72218300    72218301    +   0.982
chr18   72218300    72218307    region2 +   113.879 chr18   72218303    72218304    +   1.357
chr18   72218300    72218307    region2 +   113.879 chr18   72218304    72218305    +   4.887
chr18   72218300    72218307    region2 +   113.879 chr18   72218305    72218306    +   1.706
chr18   72218300    72218307    region2 +   113.879 chr18   72218306    72218307    +   104.947
```

The column7-column9 are sub-region, where column11 is the assigned value of sub region.

Output:
I want to assign cumulative sum for each sub region in each identifier.

```
cat input | grep region1 | awk '{ sum+=$11 } { print $0"\t"sum/$6 }'
```

this gives correct expected output for one identifier

```
chr6    26204834    26204839    region1 +   119.862 chr6    26204834    26204835    +   0.982   0.00819276
chr6    26204834    26204839    region1 +   119.862 chr6    26204835    26204836    +   8.487   0.0789992
chr6    26204834    26204839    region1 +   119.862 chr6    26204836    26204837    +   2.664   0.101225
chr6    26204834    26204839    region1 +   119.862 chr6    26204837    26204838    +   105.065 0.977774
chr6    26204834    26204839    region1 +   119.862 chr6    26204838    26204839    +   2.664   1
```

Similarly for another identifier

```
cat input | grep region2 | awk '{ sum+=$11 } { print $0"\t"sum/$6 }' 


chr18   72218300    72218307    region2 +   113.879 chr18   72218300    72218301    +   0.982   0.00862319
chr18   72218300    72218307    region2 +   113.879 chr18   72218303    72218304    +   1.357   0.0205393
chr18   72218300    72218307    region2 +   113.879 chr18   72218304    72218305    +   4.887   0.0634533
chr18   72218300    72218307    region2 +   113.879 chr18   72218305    72218306    +   1.706   0.0784341
chr18   72218300    72218307    region2 +   113.879 chr18   72218306    72218307    +   104.947 1
```

How do i automate this, by defining all identifier in an array and running through text file.

Comment: This question is perfectly on topic and welcome here, but based on the data you are showing, you might also be interested in our sister site: [bioinformatics.se].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
$ awk -vOFS='\t' '{ a[$4]+=$11/$6; print $0,a[$4]}' file 
chr6    26204834    26204839    region1 +   119.862 chr6    26204834    26204835    +   0.982   0.00819276
chr6    26204834    26204839    region1 +   119.862 chr6    26204835    26204836    +   8.487   0.0789992
chr6    26204834    26204839    region1 +   119.862 chr6    26204836    26204837    +   2.664   0.101225
chr6    26204834    26204839    region1 +   119.862 chr6    26204837    26204838    +   105.065 0.977774
chr6    26204834    26204839    region1 +   119.862 chr6    26204838    26204839    +   2.664   1
chr18   72218300    72218307    region2 +   113.879 chr18   72218300    72218301    +   0.982   0.00862319
chr18   72218300    72218307    region2 +   113.879 chr18   72218303    72218304    +   1.357   0.0205393
chr18   72218300    72218307    region2 +   113.879 chr18   72218304    72218305    +   4.887   0.0634533
chr18   72218300    72218307    region2 +   113.879 chr18   72218305    72218306    +   1.706   0.0784341
chr18   72218300    72218307    region2 +   113.879 chr18   72218306    72218307    +   104.947 1
```

The trick is to use the region identifier as the key for an associative array (`a`, in this case). You can then increment the value associated with that key as you read the file.